# How to ignore simulator files for Xamarin in .gitignore?

Tags: git, xamarin, gitignore

I have been banging my head on the wall every time I load up my project in an actual iPhone device I would get a list of simulator files in my git. (shown below)

[image: Github Desktop log]

I thought that by adding the whole folder of ExWU.iOS/bin/IPhone/Debug it should ignore the whole folder as a whole. Is there anything else I need to do to ignore all these files?

[image: .gitignore file]

Comment: You can use gitignore.io to do it: https://www.gitignore.io/api/xamarinstudio

Comment: Are those last 2 lines your `.gitignore` file?

Comment: @CalumHalpin Yes, it is. I have the general visual studio template for .ignore that GitHub suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're listed as changed files, meaning they're already tracked by git. The ignore file should prevent additional files in that directory from being tracked but you'll need to delete the already tracked files from HEAD if you don't want them to show up in `git status`. You can do that with:

```sh
git rm --cached ExWU.iOS/bin/IPhone/Debug/*
git commit -m <commit-message>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can exclude everything in `bin` and `obj` - there is no reason for these to be in your repo.

```
bin/
obj/
```

the Github .gitignore [template for Visual Studio](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) is a good start

Comment: You need to prepend `ExWU.iOS`

Comment: Recommend https://www.gitignore.io/ and choose `VisualStudio` which should cover your bases with `[Bb]in/` and `[Oo]bj/`.

Comment: no, you don't.   If that were true you would have to update .gitignore every time you add a new project to a repo.